# Comparing pixels in alpha-trimmed filter

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following problem. I have written code for alpha-trimmed filter in opencv library. I think that it is properly constructed but I don't know how to compare two 3 channels pixels during sorting a 'window with pixels'. In my code it is done but comparing two  but it is impossible for vectors. I assume that i should compare it one channel and after second and so on. Have you any hints for me, or could you propose some modifications in my code. This is my code.

```
int alphatrimmed(Mat img, int alpha)
{
Mat img9 = img.clone();
const int start = alpha;
const int end = 9 - alpha;
//going through whole image
for (int i = 1; i < img.rows - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < img.cols-1; j++)
{
        int k = 0;
        Vec3b element[9];
//selecting elements
        for (int m = i - 1; m < i + 2; m++)
        for (int n = j - 1; n < j + 2; n++)
            element[k++] = img.at<Vec3b>(m*img.cols + n);
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
            {
                int min = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < 9; j++)
                if (element[j] < element[min])
                    min = j;
                Vec3b temp = element[i];
                element[i] = element[min];
                element[min] = temp;
            }
            const int result = (i - 1)*(img.cols - 2) + j - 1;
            img9.at<Vec3b>(result) = element[start];
            for (int j = start + 1; j < end; j++)
                img9.at<Vec3b>(result) += element[j];
            img9.at<Vec3b>(result) /= 9 - alpha;
}
    namedWindow("AlphaTrimmed Filter", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("AlphaTrimmed Filter", img9);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time spent on solving my problem.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to indent your code legibly, especially as you prefer to avoid using parens for the body of most of your for and if statements. This is just asking for a mistake.

Comment: It is not obvious how alpha trimming could be generalized from operating on grayscale levels to RGB level vectors.  In the grayscale case, the lowest and highest alpha/2 levels values are discarded in the calculation of their window's mean.  One way to extend this to RGB is to discard the lightest and darkest pixels, ordering them by either the component sum `(R+G+B)`, or L2 norm `(R*R+G*G+B*B)`.  Another possible extension would be to discard the most "extreme" pxiels, by first calculating the window's mean RGB vector, then discarding pixels with the greatest Euclidean distance from this mean